# Issue with adding second UIPickerView on the same view ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

Essentially I simply want to add a second UIPickerView to my ViewController but do not understand why the following code does work properly.

When selecting the second text field **stopTextField** I expect the **stopPicker** UIPickerView show up, but instead the same **gradePicker** UIPickerView comes up.

It seems to compile fine, but completely ignores:

```
let stopPickerValues = ["What Stop?","Stop 1", "Stop 2", "Stop 3", "Stop 4", "Stop 5", "Stop 6", "Stop 7", "Stop 8", "Stop 9", "Stop 10"]
```

What is the issue?

**Here is the code:**

```
import UIKit

class timeselectviewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var gradeTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var stopTextField: UITextField!


    var gradePicker: UIPickerView!
    var stopPicker: UIPickerView!

    let gradePickerValues = ["select approximate arrival time","8:00 am -12:00 pm", "12:00 pm - 4:00 pm", "4:00 pm - 8:00 pm"]

    let stopPickerValues = ["What Stop?","Stop 1", "Stop 2", "Stop 3", "Stop 4", "Stop 5", "Stop 6", "Stop 7", "Stop 8", "Stop 9", "Stop 10"]

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func numberOfComponents2(in pickerView2: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{
        return gradePickerValues.count
    }

    func pickerView2(_ pickerView2: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent2 component2: Int) -> Int{
        return stopPickerValues.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return gradePickerValues[row]
    }

    func pickerView2(_ pickerView2: UIPickerView, titleForRow2 row2: Int, forComponent2 component2: Int) -> String? {
        return stopPickerValues[row2]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        gradeTextField.text = gradePickerValues[row]
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    func pickerView2(_ pickerView2: UIPickerView, didSelectRow2 row2: Int, inComponent2 component2: Int) {
        stopTextField.text = stopPickerValues[row2]
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        gradePicker = UIPickerView()
        stopPicker = UIPickerView()
        gradePicker.dataSource = self
        stopPicker.dataSource = self
        gradePicker.delegate = self
        stopPicker.delegate = self

        stopTextField.inputView = stopPicker
        gradeTextField.inputView = gradePicker
        gradeTextField.text = gradePickerValues[0]
        stopTextField.text = stopPickerValues[0]
    }
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48319579/uipickerview-for-each-text-field-with-different-arrays-swift-firebase for your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var pickerView: UIPickerView!

...


func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{
  if gradeTextField.isFirstResponder {
    return gradePickerValues.count
  } else {
    return stopPickerValues.count
  }
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
  if gradeTextField.isFirstResponder {
    return gradePickerValues[row]
  } else {
    return stopPickerValues[row]
  }
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
  if gradeTextField.isFirstResponder {
    gradeTextField.text = gradePickerValues[row]
  } else {
    stopTextField.text = stopPickerValues[row]
  }
  self.view.endEditing(true)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  pickerView = UIPickerView()
  pickerView.dataSource = self
  pickerView.delegate = self

  stopTextField.inputView = pickerView
  gradeTextField.inputView = pickerView
  gradeTextField.text = gradePickerValues[0]
  stopTextField.text = stopPickerValues[0]
}
```

The thing is your `pickerView2` methods are just being ignored. That way I posted above checks which text field is the first responder to perform the required actions or return the proper values.

**EDIT**

As pointed out by rmaddy, you only need one picker view, since you can only have one text field as first responder at a time.

Comment: It would be better to just have one picker view in addition to these changes.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @ajeferson 's answer but if you still want to use both the picker views then try this:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{

    if pickerView == gradePicker{

       return gradePickerValues.count

    }
    else{

       return stopPickerValues.count

    }
}
```

Both the delegate & datasource methods provides each object of UIPickerView, so that we can use them as we want.

Comment: Can you please take a look at my latest question? It's a bit of a more complex UIPickerView question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55831387/how-to-use-an-array-as-a-list-of-choices-in-uipickerview